# AppendChild() is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript, html, .net

this is my javascript

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function createQuestionPanel() {

            var element = document.createElement("Input");
            element.setAttribute("type", "button");
            element.setAttribute("value", "button");
            element.setAttribute("name", "button");


            var div = '<div>top div</div>';
            div[0].appendChild(element);

        }

        function formvalidate() {

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="createQuestionPanel()">
</body>
</html>
```

it is throwing error "AppendChild is not a function"  . I tried to search for solution .. it was suggested that on the place of

> div.appendChild(element);

this should be posted

> div[0].appendChild(element);

it didnt change the error . Please suggest

Comment: That value is a string, not a DOM element. Strings do not have `appendChild()` methods. Review the way you're creating the `<input>` element, you will need something similar for the `<div>`.

Comment: Just like you created input element, create a div element like that to have appendChild working

Comment: You should append the element to an element.. Create the div element with "top div" ID and: document.getElementById("top div").appendChild(element);

Answer (score 25):

Your `div` variable is a string, not a DOM element object:

```
var div = '<div>top div</div>';
```

Strings don't have an `appendChild` method. Instead of creating a raw HTML string, create the div as a DOM element and append a text node, then append the input element:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('top div'));

div.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 function createQuestionPanel() {

        var element = document.createElement("Input");
        element.setAttribute("type", "button");
        element.setAttribute("value", "button");
        element.setAttribute("name", "button");


        var div = document.createElement("div"); <------- Create DIv Node
        div.appendChild(element);<--------------------
        document.body.appendChild(div) <------------- Then append it to body

    }

    function formvalidate() {

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In this

```
var div = '<div>top div</div>';
```

"div" is not a DOM object,is just a string,and
string has no *string*.appendChild.

Here are some references that may help you on appendChild method:

```
<div id="div1">
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<script>
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
var div = '<div>top div</div>'; // you just created a text string
```

to

```
var div = document.createElement("div"); // we want a DIV element instead
div.innerHTML = "top div";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "topdiv";
div.appendChild(element);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Me i just use `$(".ClassName")[0].appendChild(div);` or  `$("#IdName")[0].appendChild(div);`  x)