# Append many divs inside of a div

Tags: javascript

In order to animate images in - I need to add many divs using Javascript over the image where at present the markup is

```
<div class="js-img-in">
 <figure><img src="test.jpg"></figure>
</div>
```

To eventually compile to

```
<div class="js-img-in">
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <figure><img src="test.jpg"></figure>
</div>
```

My code at the moment returns `appendChild is not a function`.

```
const imageAnimIn = () => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(".js-img-in");
  for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    var imageOverDivs = document.createElement('div');
    imageOverDivs.className = "js-anim-img-in";
    images.appendChild(imageOverDivs);
  }
}
```

This error took me to [this S.O article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673905/appendchild-is-not-a-function-javascript). `createTextNode` here, however, will not help me as I am adding an element node, not text.

Will `querySelectorAll` not work in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to loop through `images.length`, and use the image position? Because the result of `document.querySelectorAll` is a Node**List**, not just a single node.

```
const imageAnimIn = () => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(".js-img-in");
  for (var x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {        // Loop through each result
    for (var _ = 0; _ < 5; _++) {                  // Updated to disregard variable
      var imageOverDivs = document.createElement('div');
      imageOverDivs.className = "js-anim-img-in";
      images[x].appendChild(imageOverDivs);        // Added [x]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, `images` is actually an array containing the parent div.

Comment: This was most helpful. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You want `querySelector()`, not `querySelectorAll()`. Then you want `Node.insertBefore()`, and pass in the figure element as the second argument.

```js
const imageAnimIn = () => {
  const image = document.querySelector(".js-img-in")
  const fig = document.querySelector(".js-img-in > figure")
  for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    var imageOverDivs = document.createElement('div');
    imageOverDivs.className = "js-anim-img-in";
    image.insertBefore(imageOverDivs, fig)
  }
}

imageAnimIn()
```

```css
.js-anim-img-in::after{
   content: "New Div"
}
```

```html
<div class="js-img-in">
 <figure><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"></figure>
</div>

<!--<div class="js-img-in">
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <div class="js-anim-img-in"></div>
 <figure><img src="test.jpg"></figure>
</div>-->
```